# Umbraco Migration component, datetimeoffset becomes timespan

Tags: c#, sql-server, umbraco8

So i have set up a migration which seems to work fine, the only issues is that my datetimeoffset becomes a timespan in the database, when i run the migration.

And i cannot seem to figure out why, any help would be usefull.
Google and Umbraco forum or documentation have not been very helpfull.

Here is my complete code.

**My Schema**

```
public class ArticleLikeSchema
    {
        [PrimaryKeyColumn(AutoIncrement = true, IdentitySeed = 1)]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Liked")]
        public bool Liked { get; set; }

        [Column("UmbracoPageId")]
        public int UmbracoPageId { get; set; }

        [Column("UserID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [Column("Created")]
        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Migration**

```
public class AddArticleLikesTable : MigrationBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public AddArticleLikesTable(IMigrationContext context, ILogger logger) : base(context)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        public override void Migrate()
        {
            logger.Debug<AddArticleLikesTable>("Running migration {MigrationStep}", "AddArticleCommentsTable");

            // Lots of methods available in the MigrationBase class - discover with this.
            if (TableExists("ArticleLikes") == false)
            {
                Create.Table<ArticleLikeSchema>().Do();
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Debug<AddArticleLikesTable>("The database table {DbTable} already exists, skipping", "ArticleComments");
            }
        }
    }
```

**And my Component**

```
public class ArticleLikeMigrationComponent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IScopeProvider scopeProvider;
        private readonly IMigrationBuilder migrationBuilder;
        private readonly IKeyValueService keyValueService;

        public ArticleLikeMigrationComponent(ILogger logger, IScopeProvider scopeProvider, IMigrationBuilder migrationBuilder, IKeyValueService keyValueService)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.scopeProvider = scopeProvider;
            this.migrationBuilder = migrationBuilder;
            this.keyValueService = keyValueService;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            // Create a migration plan for a specific project/feature
            // We can then track that latest migration state/step for this project/feature
            var likesMigrationPlan = new MigrationPlan("ArticleLikes");

            // This is the steps we need to take
            // Each step in the migration adds a unique value

            likesMigrationPlan.From(string.Empty)
                .To<AddArticleLikesTable>("Article-Like-migration");

            // Go and upgrade our site (Will check if it needs to do the work or not)
            // Based on the current/latest step

            var upgrader2 = new Upgrader(likesMigrationPlan);
            upgrader2.Execute(scopeProvider, migrationBuilder, keyValueService, logger);
        }

        public void Terminate()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  If you want a date, you could use DateTime instead?

```
[Column(TypeName="DateTime")]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

You could also try:

```
public class AddExtraColumns : MigrationBase
    {
        public AddExtraColumns(IMigrationContext context) : base(context) {}

        public override void Migrate()
        {
                Create.Column("Created").OnTable("gfdgdf").AsDate(50).Nullable().Do();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am just trying to get a utc time saved in database, and i do not understand why it would change a DateTimeOffset to a timespan.

Comment: I think Jon is correct here but has a typo - he's put Created when I think he meant "DateTime" 
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]